# how to encode data so that Bash does not interfere with content (bash script using PHP)

Tags: php, xml, bash

I m using a bash script to curl an XMLRPC file.
However, the XML I am sending does often contain bash variables and other interfering characters (and/or variables) like `"`, `'`, `$`, `$HOME` etc.

I am not sure what all characters do interfere here or if this is related to something else.

When I run a very minimal XML through the same script, I get the expected results, but an XML with above chars (or variables) gives me: `parse error. not well formed`

Any help here is really appreciated!

Regards
Nikhil Gupta

**ADDED CODE:**

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST --data-urlencode "${XML}" $URL/xmlrpc.php

data1=$(php -r "echo htmlentities('$data1',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');")
data2=$(php -r "echo htmlentities('$data2',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');")
```

$XML is XML which utilizes `data1` and `data2` variables, which contain the problematic chars, e.g. the following XML gives error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>get.usage</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<struct>
<member> <name>script</name> <value> <string>#!/bin/bash echo $HOME;</string> </value> </member>
</struct>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: Not enough information.  How does PHP fit in, how are you calling curl, etc.?  Post at least the key code.

Comment: added the code.. can you please have a look now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason..
sorry to bother everyone here.. (esp. Matthew Flaschen)

Somehow, while testing different configurations, I fixed on to: `--data-urlencode`
while `--data-binary` is what curl will need.

Answer (score 1):

Use a file, rather than passing the XML on the command line.  This will help you avoid escaping issues:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST --data-urlencode @xml_filename $URL/xmlrpc.php
```

You obviously have to write to that file first.  You can use tempnam if you want a temporary name.

Comment: does not work.. I used exactly the above.. tested the xml saved in this temporary file with online xml validators and likes.. but everything seems to be right.. except that.. i just find that `$HOME` variable still in this tempfile.. which is not letting bash work with this simple file correctly, in my opinion... i tested with a tempfile and directly on command line for the same script without the `$` and it worked.